# Why do I get a NumberFormatException with this Integer.parseInt(x, y)?

Tags: java, hex, parseint

My code is simply:

```
int idec = Integer.parseInt(value, 16);
```

When I enter as value "01dae610", I correctly get "31122960".
When I enter as value "d149e510", I get a java.lang.NumberFormatException. The correct value is: "3511280912".

I have no clue why this is. Can someone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because that is outside the range of an `int`.  Use a `long`/`Long` instead.

Comment: thanks, pretty stupid from me. I thought I was well inside int range.

Answer (score 1):

`int` is *signed* in Java - so the maximum value is 2<sup>31</sup> - 1.

If you use `Long.parseLong(value, 16)` you'll get your desired value. You can then cast back to `int` if you're happy to get the right bit pattern, but interpreted as a negative value instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because it's the outside the range of `int`. You should use the `long` data type instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.MAX_VALUE` is 2147483647, which is lower than the value you are expecting.  So this string doesn't represent anything which can be parsed into an `int`.  Hence the exception.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> The int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has
>   a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647
>   (inclusive).

3,511,280,912 > 2,147,483,647, which explains the `NumberFormatException`.

However, you could use a `long`. From that same page:

> The long data type is a 64-bit signed two's complement integer. It has
>   a minimum value of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and a maximum value of
>   9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive).